# Does this ring homomorphism have finite flat dimension?

Tags: homological-algebra, homological-dimension

Let $k$ be a field and consider the ring homomorphism $f:k[x,xy,xy^2]\rightarrow k$ defined by mapping $x,xy,xy^2$ to zero in $k$.
I am trying to show that this ring homomorphism has finite flat dimension.
I am thinking that by construction, $f$ factors through the quotient ring homomorphism from the polynomial ring $k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$ to $k[x,xy,xy^2]\cong k[x_0,x_1,x_2]/(x_0x_2-x_1^2)$.Noting that $x_0,x_1,x_2$ is a regular sequence in the polynomial ring $k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$,the Koszul resolution for the $k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$-module $k$ has length 3. Hence, the $k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$-module $k$ has flat dimension at most 3.
We have a short exact sequence of $k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$-modules $0\rightarrow k[x_0,x_1,x_2]\xrightarrow{x_0x_2-x_1^2} k[x_0,x_1,x_2]\rightarrow k[x_0,x_1,x_2]/(x_0x_2-x_1^2)\rightarrow 0$.
Hence, the quotient ring homomorphism $k[x_0,x_1,x_2]\rightarrow k[x_0,x_1,x_2]/(x_0x_2-x_1^2)$ has flat dimension at most 1.
But I don’t know whether the ring homomorphism $f$ has finite flat dimension, and I am stuck here.
Your help is very much appreciated.